# What are the differences between jails and chroot?

Tags: chroot

I'm currently trying to point out the finer details between chroot spaces and jails. And clear up some of the controversy in the phrase "chroot jail."

So far I have chroot defined simplistically as "Unix command that appears to change the root directory. "

Is this an acceptable definition? and how would the definition of a jail differ?

Comment: Someone already asked it on Stackoverflow :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6393167/2315971

Comment: If you are looking for the featureset of jail, you might want to take a look at LXC.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that post actually. I was just looking for as many perspectives as I could.

Part of the reason I'm asking this question is I'm working my way up the knowledge tree to LXC and Docker and virtualisation as a whole.

Comment: You should watch the Linux Action Show's episode on jails and Docker http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/37396/docker-containers-made-easy-las-s27e01/

Comment: Hey thanks, that almost exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.